# Subclassing RxSwift/Reactive extension for stubbing

Tags: ios, swift, testing, stub, rx-swift

Say I have a `Field` class with a `harvest` function like this:

```
class Field {

    func harvest(handler: (Vegetable) -> Void) {
        …
        handler(carrot)
        …
        handler(potato)
        …
        handler(carrot)
        …
    }
}
```

I also have a *Reactive* version/API for the same function:

```
import RxSwift

extension Reactive where Base: Field {

    func harvest() -> Observable<Vegetable> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            self.base.harvest(handler: observer.onNext)

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I created a subclass of `Field` named `MockField` that overrides `harvest(:)` to invoke the handler with a set of stubbed `Vegetable`s. When using the `MockField` object like `field.harvest(:)` everything works fine and I get the stubbed vegetables.

Now I want to do the same with the Reactive extension to stub calls to `field.rx.harvest`, but I cannot override it to return stubbed Vegetables! **How can I override functions in the `rx` namespace?**

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this would not be subclassing, but defining `harvest() -> Observable<Vegetable>` in terms of `Field.harvest(handler:)`

```
import RxSwift

extension Reactive where Base: Field {

    func harvest() -> Observable<Vegetable> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            self.base.harvest(handler: observer.onNext)

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

Doing it this way you will not need to maintain two implementations of `harvest`.

*PS: The block passed to a disposable should cancel the action, not send the completed event. If there is no facility to cancel `harvest(handler:)`, you can simply return `Disposables.create()`.*

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's exactly how I am doing it, invoking the base implementation, but I didn't write it like that in the example (my fault, I will update it). However, the issue is still there. How do you override the implementation of `rx.harvest()` while testing to return stubbed `Vegetable`s? I think it is not possible to override it as it is a Reactive extension. One solution would be to extend `Field` with `rx_harvest` (not `rx.harvest`), so I can override it for testing, but then I loose the Reactive grouping. Any thoughts?

Comment: With the above implementation, you should already have the `MockVegetable` as values in the observable if used like `MockField().rx.harvest()`, right? Also, what happens when doing `extension Reactive where base: MockField { func harvest() -> Observable<Vegetable> { /* ... */ } }`?

Comment: I am doing `extension Reactive where base: MockField { func harvest() -> Observable<Vegetable> { return Observable.from([ Vegetable, … ]) } }` to return the stubbed `Vegetable`s, and I inject `MockField` to the class that uses it. However, as `MockField` is not overriding `Field`'s `rx.harvest`, the mock implementation is never called.